# Tapestry - receiving two contexts and using them in a Form

Tags: java, tapestry

I receive two contexts called uId and oId (both ones long).

With onActivate I save userId context in my variable userId, same for orderId.
When I´m inside onActivate I can print those two variables but if I use (for example) a form, userId is null.

How could I have access to those variables in my form.

Here the code:

```
public class newMessage{

@Property
private Long userId;

@Property
private Long orderId;

@Component
private Form newMessageForm;


void onActivate(Long userId, Long orderId){
    this.userId = userId;
    System.out.println("User Id: " + userId);
    this.orderId = orderId;
    System.out.println("Order Id: " + orderId);
}


@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALIDATE, component = "newMessageForm")
public void checkForm() {
    System.out.println("userId: " + userId);
    System.out.println("orderId: " + orderId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@PageActivationContext` now supports multiple values via the new [index](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/PageActivationContext.html#index%28%29) feature added in 5.4. If you use this then you don't need explicit `onActivate` and `onPassivate` declarations.

eg:

```
public class NewMessage {
   @Property
   @PageActivationContext(index=0)
   private Long userId;

   @Property
   @PageActivationContext(index=1)
   private Long orderId;
```

More info [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2138)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the onPassivate method which adds the activation context to links and forms so that in next requests these values will be available again. This method should return exactly what you expect in the onActivate method.
Some more info can be found here:

[JumpStart onActivate/onPassivate](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/navigation/onactivateandonpassivate/3)

So in your case adding following method should do it:

```
Object[] onPassivate() {
    return new Object[] { userId, orderId };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Nathan. I´ll try it.

Comment: Ok, set as accepted answer if this was the solution to your problem.